# How to save and keep the wall paper for use in a newer version of Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-background

Can I copy and keep the wall paper files from 16.04.4 LTS and use it in 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 5):

After update, you can install wallpapers from old releases:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-xxxxx
```

Where -xxxxx comes from the list below:

```
ubuntu-wallpapers: Ubuntu Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-artful: Ubuntu 17.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-bionic: Ubuntu 18.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-karmic: Ubuntu 9.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-lucid: Ubuntu 10.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick: Ubuntu 10.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-natty: Ubuntu 11.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric: Ubuntu 11.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-precise: Ubuntu 12.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal: Ubuntu 12.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-raring: Ubuntu 13.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy: Ubuntu 13.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty: Ubuntu 14.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-utopic: Ubuntu 14.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-vivid: Ubuntu 15.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-wily: Ubuntu 15.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial: Ubuntu 16.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-yakkety: Ubuntu 16.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-zesty: Ubuntu 17.04 Wallpapers
```

Comment: How to get the above list? when we give the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial` where do they store?

Comment: Google 'ubuntu-wallpapers packages' ... this is one of the first links: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinov7l6tXbAhXCB5oKHZFNDzoQFgg2MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2Fubuntu%2F%2Bsource%2Fubuntu-wallpapers&usg=AOvVaw1eRVMCDyqd-GiTUGogWz2I

Comment: @PRATAP They get installed into the same location as your answer below.

Comment: One thing to note here.  If you are running 16.04 the wallpapers for 17.04, 17.10 and 18.04 are not available for install.  You can't install forward for the wallpapers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Manually download ubuntu-wallpapers_16.04.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb from the official Ubuntu download webpage [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/ubuntu-wallpapers/download).
2. Open the ubuntu-wallpapers_16.04.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb with Archive Manager and extract the file named warty-final-ubuntu.png.
3. Replace the existing warty-final-ubuntu.png file at `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` with the new warty-final-ubuntu.png file that you extracted from ubuntu-wallpapers_16.04.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb.
4. Apply the new wallpaper by going to System Settings -> *Background* -> click the existing *Background* wallpaper -> select a new Background wallpaper from the wallpaper image gallery -> click the green *Select* button in the top right corner.